# is onchange event case sensitive?

Tags: javascript, html

Does onchange event of select tag case sentive? Can't i use ONCHANGE instead of onchange?

Comment: This is something you can test for yourself quite easily don't you think?

Comment: i tried it in in normal javascrip ONCHANGE worked there,but when i used it inside my dojo code it didnot work

Comment: @akshay - details like `dojo` and _what you did try_ are important to understanding the question. You really should include them in your question.

Comment: tried it at http://jsfiddle.net/B64Jc/3/

Comment: _It's not clear if you're referring to the X/HTML `onchange="..."` attribute or attaching an `foo.onchange = ...` event handler in JavaScript._ So while it's not an answer to your question: you should not use any JavaScript attributes in your HTML code, including `onchange`. Just as [you should not mix CSS with HTML](http://phrogz.net/CSS/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#separatestyle), you should not mix JavaScript with HTML. Instead, programmatically attach your event handlers to your HTML _with JavaScript_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is case-sensitive. You can't use ONCHANGE instead of onchange. Why this is a very prohibitive issue, you may want to explain.

Comment: Question is about both html and javascript. html is not case sensitive. See the other answer

Answer (score 11):

Case insensitive if you are writing HTML. Case sensitive if you are assigning a function to it through JavaScript.